# Hide some properties in PropertyGrid at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am doing a project that allows user to customized the properties of a `Control`. I have a form that has a control like `Label`, `TextBox`, `Button` and `PropertyGrid` control. When the user clicks on the `Label` i am showing the properties of the `Label` in the `ProeprtyGrid` which is all working fine using below code:

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = SelectedControl;
```

But I just want to show some properties like `BackColor`, `Font`, `ForeColor`, `Text`. Is it possible to hide the properties since I don't want user to change it or show to them? If yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are looking for custom type descriptors.

While the other answer is sharing correct information about `Browsable` attribute and `BrowsableAttributes` of `PropertyGrid`, but I'd say it's not a proper practical solution for the problem.

It's not practical to set `Browsable` attribute, or any other custom attributes for existing control classes like `Label`, `Button`, and so on. Because in this way, the op needs to override all properties of those classes and decorate them with suitable attribute. And even worst, not all propertied are overridable.

**What's the practical solution?**

As I mentioned earlier, I believe you are looking for custom type descriptors. You can provide metadata about an object assigning a new `TypeDescriptor` or implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or deriving from `CustomTypeDescriptor`.

**Example**

Here for example, I create a `CustomObjectWrapper` class deriving from `CustomTypeDescriptor` which accepts an object in constructor. This way I can simply filter the properties of the wrapped object by overriding `GetProperties`.

Then instead of assigning `button1` to `PropertyGrid`, I wrap it in `CustomObjectWrapper` and assing the `CustomObjectWrapper` to property grid. This way it just shows the filtered properties and the properties are actually come from `button1`.

Here is the implantation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class CustomObjectWrapper : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public object WrappedObject { get; private set; }
    public List<string> BrowsableProperties { get; private set; }
    public CustomObjectWrapper(object o)
        :base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(o).GetTypeDescriptor(o))
    {
        WrappedObject = o;
        BrowsableProperties = new List<string>() { "Text", "BackColor" };
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { });
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                             .Where(p=>BrowsableProperties.Contains(p.Name))
                             .Select(p => TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(
                                 WrappedObject.GetType(),
                                 p,
                                 p.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().ToArray()))
                             .ToArray();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
    }
}
```

And as usage:

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new CustomObjectWrapper(button1);
```

You can simply add new property names to `BrowsableProperties` of the `CustomObjectWrapper`. It's a public property.

Comment: What do you think about having a Designer class that inherits [ControlDesigner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and overrides its [PreFilterProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.prefilterproperties(v=vs.110).aspx)? The `properties` parameter is a `IDictionary<string, PropertyDescriptor>`. Properties could then be removed using `properties.Remove("[PropertyName]")`.

Comment: I tried this one and it's works great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the feedback. If the requirement was for design-time, I'd used `ControlDesigner`, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38771092/3110834) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50772584/3110834). But here the OP is asking it for run-time, by setting `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject`. That's why I used `TypeDescriptor`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was more interested in your opinion on the matter (eventual problem, drawbacks...). Btw, those answers didn't come up on a search. That's a bummer.

Answer (score 5):

## UPDATE

Please note this is only useful for Hiding properties (when you can). *Reza Aghaei* answer is actually the correct answer.

I'll leave this here as it's suitable for the other case when you just simply want to hide a property when you have access to it.

**Original**

Easiest way is probably to use

```
[Browsable(false)]
```

[BrowsableAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a
>   Properties window.

```
[Browsable(false)]
public int SecretSquirrels
{
  get; set;
}
```

Also as pointed out by *Marc Gravell*, there is also

[PropertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the browsable attributes associated with the object that
>   the property grid is attached to.

Comment: generalizing that a bit, there is a [`BrowsableAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property that you can use to provide custom filters (or : different views on the same object), but: it is *quite likely* that `[Browsable(false)]` does everything OP needs

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to create a Custom `PropertyGrid`? Say I want to show this list `string[] ShowThisPropertyList = new string[] { "Text", "BackColor", "ForeColor" };`

Comment: @Zhyke You are probably doing to have to create a new object that reference the properties in the label you want, and thats the one you put in the propertyGrid

Comment: While this answer is sharing correct information about `Browsable` attribute and `BrowsableAttributes` of `PropertyGrid`, but I'd say it's not a proper practical solution for the problem. It's not practical to set `Browsable` attribute, or any other custom attributes for existing control classes like `Label`, `Button`, and so on. Because in this way, the op needs to override all properties of those classes and decorate them with suitable attribute. And even worst, not all propertied are overridable.