# Hide the 'Name' property of an inherited control

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to hide the `Name` property in the `ProeprtyGrid`? I already hides all other property like `Font`, `BackColor` and other properties.
I just want to show the `Text` property. Anyway, I am working on a end user form designer like visual studio designer. So i am only showing some property to the user. I inherited the control and i am using the following code to hide those property:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public override Color BackColor { get; set; }
```

All works okay. It hides the property except for the two property named `Locked` and `Name`. I am using the same code as above but still showing in the property. Actually the property `Name` is showing twice.

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
private new string Name { get; set; }

[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool Locked;
```

Or if it's not possible to hide the `Name` property, why does it displays the Name `property` twice?

[image]

Comment: Why would you hide the name property?

Comment: I don't want the user to change/show the name of the control. I just want them to change the Text property.

Comment: Actually I just want it to hide in `PropertyGrid`.

Comment: which one is derived , which is a parent control ?

Comment: @Z.R.T. i'm using the `Label` as parent control.

Comment: @John yap. I just want user to change the display text. No need to rename.

Comment: @John I already handled in the code the name of the control. So no need for the user to change the name of the control. Just the display text.

Comment: The user does not have any access to the source code. As i mentioned, i already handled the name in the code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: lol. Did you read my post above? I am doing an end user form designer. This will use by user for personal customization.

Comment: Perhaps you should open with that. I missed that.

Comment: @Zhyke i think you can't hide field name from property grid. But you can make it read only, means name can be edited only in Form designer -> Properties Window

Comment: Maybe a wrapper like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611870/hide-some-properties-in-propertygrid) could help.