# Editable Button Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, textbox

I have a button which created at runtime

```
Button myBtn = new Button();
Initialize(myBtn);
myBtn.Click += myBtn_Click();
myBtn.Text="Add or Edit Text";//default text string
```

when user `click` `myBtn`, it will highlight existing text and it is editable and user can type any new `text`.

How can i make `button control` editable during `click event`?

After user clicking and typing any string, the result will be `myBtn.Text = "Any Text"`

Example: `myBtn.Text="Add or Edit Text";` //before clicking

`myBtn.Text="any text or string that user type it";` //after clicking

Comment: What you actually want to do? seems to be confusing

Comment: We call this a `TextBox`

Comment: @Justcode if a user click a button, existing button.text will highlight and user can now type anything he/she want and will update to new string

Comment: @TheGeneral yes it is like a textbox but in a button control.

Comment: This seems like a flagrant misuse of standard windows controls, just saying, who is going to know to click the button to change the text? however, you might want overlay a textbox on the button, or use a popup dialog to enter the text

Comment: No need to overlay, in fact all controls have `Controls` collection and you can add another control to their control collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `TextBox` to the `Button` control and create `EditableButton` control having the following methods and properties:

- `EditMode`: Gets or sets how editing will start. It can be `OnPressF2`, `OnClick`, `Programmatically`. Depending to the value of this property, editing will start by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or on `Click` or by your code calling `BeginEdit`.
- `BeginEdit()`: Starts editing by showing the `TextBox`.
- `EndEdit()`: Ends editing and hides the text box and commit text of `TextBox` as text of the `Button`.
- `CancelEdit()`: Cancels the editing and hides the text box.
- `IsEditing`: Determines if the control is in edit mode and `TextBox` is visible.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to end edit and committing the text.
- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to cancel edit and discard changes.

**EditableButton**

Here is an example of a button control having above properties and methods. You can enhance it by adding some events like `BeginingEditing` or `EndingEdit` or exposing some properties or events of the `TextBox`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class EditablButton : Button
{
    private TextBox txt;
    public enum EditModes { OnPressF2, OnClick, Programmatically }
    public EditModes EditMode { get; set; } = EditModes.OnPressF2;
    public bool IsEditing => txt.Visible;
    public EditablButton()
    {
        txt = new TextBox();
        txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        txt.Visible = false;
        txt.Multiline = true;
        txt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.KeyDown += Txt_PreviewKeyDown;
    }
    private void Txt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            EndEdit();
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            CancelEdit();
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        txt.Text = this.Text;
        txt.SelectAll();
        txt.Visible = true;
        txt.Focus();
    }
    public void EndEdit()
    {
        this.Text = txt.Text;
        txt.Visible = false;
        this.Focus();
    }
    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        txt.Visible = false;
        this.Focus();
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (!IsEditing && EditMode == EditModes.OnPressF2 && keyData == Keys.F2)
        {
            BeginEdit();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EditMode == EditModes.OnClick)
            BeginEdit();
        else
            base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is almost what i'm looking for but instead of pressing F2, its would be better left mouse click

Comment: I've created a property for that. `EditMode`, you can set it to `OnPressF2`, `OnClick` or `Programmatically`. After you dropped and instance of the control on form, just set its `EditMode` to `OnClick` to start editing by click. You can also change the default value in the code.

Comment: I add something in my code. I want to capture the click event of button.                                                                                                             
            `string newString = "";
            myBtn.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                newString = myBtn.Text;
            };` It seems it doesnt work , i think its because the click event is already implemented in button.

Comment: `if (EditMode == EditModes.OnClick) BeginEdit();` It disables `Click` event becase it's not calling `base.OnClick(e);`. If for any reason you want `Click` event raise (while I disagree on this idea), you can uncomment the `else` statement and let `base.OnClick(e);` calls anyway, regardless of the edit mode.

Comment: If you are interested to get notified about changed text, it's enough to subscribe `TextChange` event of the button.

Comment: As a side-note (maybe off-topic) if you are creating an application for editing some control properties at run-time, I suggest using `PropertyGrid`.  You may want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40209045/3110834) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618536/3110834).

Comment: It seems the post answers the question. Let me know if you have any question about the answer in scope of the question.

Comment: `public EditModes EditMode { get; set; } = EditModes.OnClick;` worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can put a text box where User can write some text & then on button click you can set the text:

```
myBtn.Text=txt_value.Text;
```

Or you can try the following to Highlight the Text:

Make the TextBox by Default `Visible=False;`

On `myBtn_Click`

```
txt_value.Visible=True;
myBtn.FontBold=True;
myBtn.Text=txt_value.Text; //to change the text each time the button is clicked
```